# Setting up dataframe in python

Tags: python, r, dataframe, subset

I typically work in R but I am attempting to recreate some R scripts in Python.  I have been semi-succussful but still not getting what I need - or getting it efficiently.  I have a large data set of student data and I am trying to create a new dataframe selecting only the grade, gpa and ACT columns for a specific class.   In R I have

```
data = read.csv('path.csv', na='NULL')
dat <- subset(data, classnumber == 121 & grade != 'W' & grade != 'P')

convert_grades <- function(x) {
  A <- factor(x, levels=c("A","B","C","D","F"))
  values <- c(1,1,1,0,0)
  values[A]
}       

dataset = data.frame(convert_grades(dat$grade), dat$GPA, dat$act)
```

There are two issues I am having when trying to convert this to python

1) I can't convert the letter grades to a 0 or 1.  I have been able to convert them to numeric values based on their location in the alphabet but not into a 0 or 1 format.

2) When I subset my data in python based on the class number I have to use

```
dat=dataset.loc[(data.classnumber == 121) | (data.classnumber == '121')]
```

using '121' returns everything but the last 15 rows and just using 121 provides those last 15 rows.  I assume that the last 15 rows are different type for some reason.  Is there a way to make this column one single type?
In R I know I would use

```
as.numeric(data$classnumber)
```

Any python equivalent?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding you are facing two problems

1. To convert letter grades into binary grades.
   I assume you have successfully created a dataframe in python and imported the columns "Grades","GPA","ACT". For your conversion use a dictionary with keys being the letter grade i.e, ('A','B','C','D','E') to zeros and ones.

Solution: Use map() function or replace()

```
    convert ={'A' : 1, 'B' : 1, 'C' : 1, 'D' : 0, 'E' : 0}
```

maps the grades to 0 & 1 and undefined values to NaN

```
    df['Grades'] = df['Grades'].map(convert)
```

Replace the values under column 'Grades' with 1s and 0s without affecting grades which are not defined

```
    df.replace(convert,inplace=True)
```

2. Looks like the classnumber contains values of two different datatypes. One solution is to convert it to a single datatype preferably int

Check current datatype
`df.dtypes()`

convert the column to int datatype

```
    df['classnumber'].astype(int)
```

P.S: This is my first answer in Stackoverflow. Any tips or edits needed to the answer are welcomed.

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I needed.  Great first answer!

Comment: Thank you. This gives me motivation to work more for the community